# Find the differential of an inverse function of $G(u,v) = (u^4 - u + uv + v^2,\cos u + \sin v)$

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I am attempting to solve this problem:

> Show that the system of equations
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> x &= u^4 - u + uv + v^2, \\
> y &= \cos u + \sin v
> \end{align}
> $$
>   can be solved for $(u,v)$ as a smooth function $F$ of $(x,y)$, in some neighborhood
>   of $(0,0)$, in such a way that $(u,v) = (0,0)$ when $(x,y) = (0,1)$. What is the
>   differential of the resulting function $F$ at $(0,1)$?

If I define $G(u,v) = (u^4 - u + uv + v^2,\cos u + \sin v)$, then $G^{-1} = F$. But
$$
\det dG^{-1}(0,0) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}
= 0.
$$

This means that I cannot use the Inverse Function Theorem to show $G^{-1}$ is smooth near $(0,0)$. I suspect that due to the periodic nature of $y$, there may be a different inverse function that does allow me to use the Inverse Function Theorem. However, the problem gives me $F(0,1) = (0,0)$ so I feel like I should be using $(u,v)=(0,0)$ to find the inverse function.

Comment: You made a mistake while calculating the Jacobian of the function $G$:
\begin{equation}
d G = \begin{pmatrix} 4u^3-1+v & u + 2v \\ -\sin u & \cos v \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Evaluating this at $(u,v) = (0,0)$ we get 
\begin{equation}
dG(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix} -1  & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
so that $det\,dG^{-1} (0,0) = -1 \neq 0$ and the Inverse Function Theorem applies.

Answer (score 1):

As [pg_star](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/641738/pg-star) pointed out in the comments, I had calculated the Jacobian of $G$ incorrectly.
$$
dG(0,0) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Because $G(0,0) = (0,1)$, the Inverse Function Theorem says that $dF(0,1)$ is the inverse of $dG(0,0)$, which is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
.$$